Bazel python interpreter commandline flags
How to make a py_binary target that accepts interpreter flags such as -OO and -W?
I want the bazel_binary to create an executable that runs python -OO -W main.py.
py_binary(
    name="main",
    srcs=["main.py"],
    ???=["-OO", "-W"],
)

args passes the arguments to main.py. Is there no mechanism for py_binary target to specify interpreter flags?

Maybe ask this question at https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_python/discussions

From the py_binary documentation, you should be able to use args = ["-OO", "-W"]
